# Changing the UINavigationBar back button to an icon and retaining the swipe to go back

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar

is there anyway to change the back button to an icon in the UINavigationBar. I know I can do something like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back"];
    image = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(goBack)];
```

however I want to retain the ability to swipe the controller right to go back. Is this possible at all?

Comment: The gesture will not be influenced if you change the buttons.

Comment: @Krumelur this wrong: Setting a custom BarButtonItem disables the swipe gesture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the backbutton appearance in your AppDelegate. This won't affect the back-swipe gesture.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: pretty nice way to customize the back button, but this will globally affect the bar button right ?

Comment: thanks mate this worked! had to put this in the previous view controller though: self.title=@""; to disable the title.

Comment: @VinayJain yeah it's global

Comment: You're welcome. @VinayJain: yes this affects all backButtons throughout your app

Comment: @croX I have disable the title but now there is no title for the view controller in the navigation bar (duh...obviously). I actually need that title though. Is there anyway to show the back button icon without the title?

Comment: You can: Open your storyboard and select the particular viewController's navigationItem. Then open the Attributes Inspector and insert a " " space in the "BackButton" field. You can then set your title, and you won't see it in your backbutton :)

Comment: just did it like this in the previous view controller: UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;. Thanks

Comment: @VinayJain You can use -appearanceWhenContainedIn: to limit the effect to navigation bars within your own subclass of UINavigationController.

Comment: Thanks @Dex will try it as soon as I am on my Mac

Comment: A little offtopic, but are you guys brothers, croX Kex Dex